# Getting permutations iteratively using a stack with Python

Tags: python, stack, permutation

Below is my try of recursive version. How implement the solution iteratively using a stack?

```
def get_prems(lst):
    prems = []
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return prems
    if len(lst) == 1:
        prems.append([lst[0]])
        return prems
    for n in lst:
        lst_without_n = list(lst)
        lst_without_n.remove(n)
        for n_prem in get_prems(lst_without_n):
            n_prem = [n] + n_prem
            prems.append(n_prem)

    return prems
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't working for me. Here's what I get:

```
my1st = [1, 2, 3]
get_prems(my1st)
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

I'd use the itertools module instead:

```
list(permutations(my1st))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```